# Restrict HTTP request based on HTTP Protocol in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, httprequest, http-protocols

I want to restrict the HTTP request based on the HTTP request protocol lower than 2.0 in ASP.NET Core.
Can we add any policy in the **startup.cs** file that will restrict the HTTP request based on the HTTP protocol?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use middleware to get the protocol of the current request, and then judge whether it is lower than `HTTP/2`. For example:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var Protocol = context.Request.Protocol;
    if (float.Parse(Protocol.Remove(0,Protocol.Length - 1)) < 2)
    {
        //You can use other methods to restrict requests
        //If using redirection will initiate another request, please make sure that the protocol used by this request is not lower than HTTP/2
        context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error");
    }          
    await next.Invoke();
});
```